# Javascript .filter all items with index less than certain value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to filter all the items in the initialItems which has an index lesser than the current item. For example, if the name is CM, i need to get QS, IT and AB to be displayed in a draggable dropdown menu. However, I am stuck on how to use the filter and findIndex javascript function to perform this action.

**Code with filter function:**

```
  getItems(itemName) {
    let index = this.state.initialItems.findIndex(x => x.name == itemName);
    for (var i = 0; i < initialItems.length; i++) {
      let items = this.state.initialItems.filter((item) => i < index);

    }
  }
```

**Console.log object of initialItems:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "QS",
        "isTrue": false,
        "id": "ccc"
    },
    {
        "name": "IT",
        "isTrue": null,
        "id": "bbb"
    },
    {
        "name": "AB",
        "isTrue": null,
        "id": "aaa"
    },
    {
        "name": "CM",
        "isTrue": null,
        "id": "ddd"
    }
]
```

Comment: There is the `slice` array method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getItems(itemName) {
  const index = items.findIndex(item => item.name === itemName);
  return items.slice(0, index);
};

getItems("CM");
```